# groups.Groups.created_by: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Groups.created_by' clashes withfield name 'User.groups'

Tags: python, django, database, model, migration

I am trying to migrate these two models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

# Groups Model
class Cluster(models.Model):

    grp_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grp_status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grp_description = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='created',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, 
        through='UserGroup',
        through_fields=('user', 'group'),
        related_name='members'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.grp_name

#user groups
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'user'
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Cluster,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'group'
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

But I have got this error:

```
    ERRORS:
groups.Cluster.members: (fields.E339) 'UserGroup.group' is not a foreign key to 'User'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'User': user?
groups.Cluster.members: (fields.E339) 'UserGroup.user' is not a foreign key to 'Cluster'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Cluster': group?
```

I want to make many-to-many relationship between the users and groups. That is the users can be in many groups and groups will have many users. Why is my code wrong? And how should I fix it? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User related_name parameter:

```
 created_by=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="created")
```

Comment: No i changed the name but still its giving the same error. I think that is because i am using two foreign key in Groups Model. Is there anything you can help with that?

Comment: Add a parameter called related_name In the foreign key fields

Comment: after putting the related_name it gives me this                                                                        ERRORS:
groups.Cluster.members: (fields.E339) 'UserGroup.group' is not a foreign key to 'User'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'User': user?
groups.Cluster.members: (fields.E339) 'UserGroup.user' is not a foreign key to 'Cluster'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Cluster': group?

Comment: have you added different relate_name to all foreign key fields? @AdilShaikh